# Why IndexOutOfBoundsException was not thrown when I used java substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex) even my arguments were out of bounds?

Tags: java

When I was trying the substring() method I found that java didn't throw IndexOutOfBoundsException in this code even though the endIndex is out of bounds

```
String str1 = "abcdefg";
System.out.println(str1.substring(3,7));
```

When I changed the endIndex to 8 then java throwed IndexOutOfBoundsException in this code

```
String str1 = "abcdefg";
System.out.println(str1.substring(3,8));
```

I already read the documentation about this form of substring
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-

I just remembered that in other programming language like C there is a character String called null-terminated String that is added at the end of the String
here are some of my references
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_strings.htm

So, I'm just wondering, does java add a null-terminated String at the end of a string that's why this code fragment "System.out.println(str1.substring(3,7));" didn't throw IndexOutOfBoundsException?

Comment: There is no null terminated character in Java, or at least you can't "see" it as a consumer of Java's string API.  The behavior you are seeing is expected from reading the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)).

Comment: Well, I thought that when substring is used, java will point to the endIndex that I put then move backwards by 1. So, my assumption was wrong after all.

Comment: Now I see what you werr thinking, and yes it was a good guess.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `substring(start, end)` function specifies an inclusive `start` and an exclusive `end` index.

This way, you can specify an `index` that's 1 greater than the max index to indicate that you want to go all the way to the end of the string (although, in that case, you should probably just use the single-argument `substring(start)` that automatically grabs to the end of the string).

This is useful if you're programmatically calling the `substring(start, end)` function w/ computed `start` and `end` values without having to check for the size of the string and invoking the single-argument version.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation you linked to:

> The substring begins at the specified beginIndex and extends to the character at index endIndex - 1.

So `str1.substring(3,7)` is actually taking a substring from index 3 through index 6.

Answer (score 0):

What was stated in the other 2 solutions is correct. When you do:

```
String str1 = "abcdefg";
System.out.println(str1.substring(3,7));
```

This is what happens:

```
          v        v
[a][b][c][d][e][f][g]          --- return "defg"   
[0][1][2][3][4][5][6][7]       --- Grabbing index 3 to 6
```

It is reading from index 3 to 6 because the substring reads 1 character before the stated end-index.

---

However, when you do this:

```
String str1 = "abcdefg";
System.out.println(str1.substring(3,8));
```

This is what happens:

```
          v           v
[a][b][c][d][e][f][g]          --- out of bounds, trying to read after last character   
[0][1][2][3][4][5][6][7]       --- Grabbing index 3 to 7
```